# Void pointer conversion error

Tags: c++, void-pointers

Here is an except of my code

poly.h

```
#include "gf.h"    
typedef struct polynome {
int deg, size;
gf_t * coeff;
} * poly_t; /* polynomial has coefficients in the finite field */
class Polinomio{
   public:
     int poly_degppf(poly_t g);
```

poly.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "gf.h"
#include "poly.h"
Polinomio::Polinomio(int n){
    printf("Hola como estas");
}
int Polinomio::poly_degppf(poly_t g) {
int i, d, res;
poly_t *u;
d = poly_deg(g);
u = malloc(d * sizeof (poly_t*));
```

Why do i get this error?

```
poly.cpp: In member function ‘int Polinomio::poly_degppf(polynome*)’:
poly.cpp:261: error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘polynome**’
```

Comment: It looks like you're missing the bottom half of your header file.

Comment: What in the world does this question have to do with `#define`?

Comment: Worst-titled question ever...

Answer (score 2):

C++ is a little bit more cautious about types than C. So you have to cast your `malloc` call. Like this:

```
u = (poly_t*)malloc(d * sizeof (poly_t));
```

Notice that I also changed the parameter on `sizeof`, you want the size of the type not the size of a pointer to the type.

Finally, don't use `malloc` on C++, use `new`.

One more thing, `poly_t` is already a pointer type, you probably want to declare `u` as just `poly_t u;` But I don't know how you are using it on the rest of the code.

Answer (score 1):

Because C++ does not allow the implicit conversion of a `void *` to another object pointer. You need to make the cast explicit:

```
u = static_cast<polynome**>(malloc(d * sizeof(polynome*)));
```

Basically, whenever one conversion is implicit (such as `T *` to `void *`), the opposite conversion requires a `static_cast`.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Mais oui... (You've been defeated by C-style typedef madness!)

Comment: ah... that is true.  But your types are still incorrect.  You've mixed double and triple indirection.